# Powershell to sort through times

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

When running a powershell script I am able to find the machines on my network that have BSOD and have a minidump file.  When weeding through all the data I noticed many of the workstations had times that it occurred at the same time each day.  Is there a way to use powershell to sort through the data to show only the workstations where the times of the bsod are the same daily?

The script I am using to detect the machines that have had the bsod.

```powershell
$Computers = get-content "C:\users\mike\Computerlist.txt"
$OutFile = "C:\users\mike\Results.txt"

#Erase an existing output file so as not to duplicate data
out-file -filepath $OutFile

foreach ($Computer in $Computers)
{
    if (test-path \\$computer\c$\Windows\Minidump)  #test to make sure the file exists
    {
        #Get the CreationTime value from the file
        $FileDate = (Get-ChildItem \\$computer\c$\Windows\Minidump).CreationTime

        #Write the computer name and File date separated by a unique character
       "$Computer | $FileDate" | out-file -FilePath $OutFile -Append
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to be a little more specific about how granular you need to be about the timestamps.  It's unlikely the files will have the same timestamp, down to the millisecond, every day.

Comment: Honestly hour and minute is as close as I need it.

Comment: Something is up with `$Computer | $FileDate"`. You have a quoting issue there. I tried to fix it assuming it was a typo but I'm not sure what the intention was there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think that you might need to be more clear on what you need to do with the data but the work is still the same. I would think that you should capture all the results into an object that you could group and sort on

```
$results = @() # Capture all the data here.

ForEach ($Computer in $Computers){
    if (Test-Path "\\$computer\c$\Windows\Minidump")  #test to make sure the file exists
    {
        #Get the CreationTime value from the file
        $fileData = Get-ChildItem "\\$computer\c$\Windows\Minidump" | 
                Select Name,@{L="Date";E={Get-Date($_.CreationTime) -Format "ddMMyyyyHHmm"}} |
                Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Computer" -Value $computer -PassThru

        $results += $fileData
    }
}
```

- Navigate each computer and get the minidump file data assuming that it exists.
- For each file we format the creation data so that it is a date with seconds.
- Add to that information the computer name where the file was generated.

This would create output like the following

```
Name                Date         Computer
----                ----         --------
010615-28142-01.dmp 060120151213 awesome 
121714-34179-01.dmp 171220141310 awesome 
121714-36441-01.dmp 171220141310 awesome 
010615-28142-01.dmp 080120151307 C3959   
121714-34179-01.dmp 080120151308 C3959   
121714-36441-01.dmp 080120151308 C3959
```

So we have the file names, formatted time stamps of the files and the associated computer of those files. Now we can use `Group-Object` to collect and sort that data. (This is the part where you might need to chime in with your intentions)

```
$results | Group-Object date

Count Name                      Group                                                                                                                        
----- ----                      -----                                                                                                                        
    1 060120151213              {@{Name=010615-28142-01.dmp; Date=060120151213; Computer=awesome}}                                                           
    2 171220141310              {@{Name=121714-34179-01.dmp; Date=171220141310; Computer=awesome}, @{Name=121714-36441-01.dmp; Date=171220141310; Computer...
    1 080120151307              {@{Name=010615-28142-01.dmp; Date=080120151307; Computer=C3959}}                                                             
    2 080120151308              {@{Name=121714-34179-01.dmp; Date=080120151308; Computer=C3959}, @{Name=121714-36441-01.dmp; Date=080120151308; Computer=C...
```

Ignoring the bad data sample used for this you can see that it groups the objects by the "creation dates" of the minidumps. If there were files across systems that happened at the same minute of a given day they would be grouped here.

Before we get to crazy you could just sort the results as well since that would also show you the relationship you woudlnt even need to do the crazy stuff with the `CreationTime`

```
$results | Sort-Object Date
```

**Update from comments**

So if you wanted to make a report of the information you could manipulate the results like this.

```
$results | Group-Object Date | ForEach-Object{
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Time = $_.Name
        Computers = $_.Group.Computer -join ";"
    }
}
```

That will output every time (to the minute) that a BSOD occured. If there are multiple computers then they will be semicolon delimited in the parameter `Computers`. You could output this with `Export-CSV` easily if you wanted to.

Comment: My end intention is to be able to provide this with a software developer to provide another string of data that has common denominators.  Back story was we have a software that is developed for our company and was tested in a small sample and then the directive was given to send it to the entire enterprise without a thorough testing run.  This has caused about 1/3 of our enterprise of 20000 workstations to BSOD multiple times since deployment of the software.  I have provided them with the number count, but they want fine detail on what workstations are doing it daily at the same time.